# WooCommerce : how to save customer address details

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, woocommerce

I am writing a Wordpress plugin for WooCommerce.
I want to update the customer's delivery address.
Here is my code :

```
$woo_customer = WC()->customer;
$woo_customer->set_location( $address->country,
                             $address->state, 
                             $address->postCode, 
                             $address->city );
$woo_customer->set_address( $address->street1 );
$woo_customer->set_address_2( $address->street2 );
$woo_customer->save_data();
```

That all runs just fine, and if I check say country value it appears to have saved:

```
error_log( $address->country ); // outputs "United Kingdom"  
error_log( $woo_customer->get_country() ); // outputs "United Kingdom"
```

However when I look at this user in the Wordpress admin (*Users > All Users > (my user)*) their **Customer Shipping Address** details are all blank - nothing has saved.

---

**How do I tell WooCommerce/Wordpress to update the users shipping address with these details I have entered?**

Answer (score 4):

The customer is just the user attached to the order, updates need to be made to the user using the `update_user_meta();` function, documented [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta), in order for the changes to appear in (Users > All Users > (your user)):

```
$woo_customer = wp_get_current_user();
$metaKeyVals = array(
    'shipping_address_1' => $address->street1,
    'shipping_address_2' => $address->street2,
    'shipping_country' => $address->country,
    'shipping_state' => $address->state,
    'shipping_postcode' => $address->postCode,
    'shipping_city' => $address->city
);
foreach ($metaKeyVals as $key => $val) {
    update_user_meta($woo_customer->ID, $key, $val);
}
```